# Word/phrase for "last minute love confession"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I want a word or a small phrase which can be used in place of "last minute love confession". I specifically use "last minute" for when the confessor and the confessee are going away from each other, like the last day of college.

I think it's unlikely that english has such a construct. But any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The best phrase I got for my requirements from the answers here is a "parting love note"

Comment: I removed the "any language" requirements

Comment: A *parting note.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single recognised English construct for this, but something that would convey the correct meaning could be "at the eleventh hour [to mean 'at the last minute' or 'just before it was too late'] he confessed his undying love for her"

Answer (score 0):

You can roughly use "swan song."

It means:

1. A farewell appearance or final act or pronouncement.
2. A song of great sweetness said to be sung by a dying swan

Its definition from macmillan dictionary is " the last performance, speech, or work in the career of a well-known person."

Or "the last sweet nothings" may fit.

Comment: You can paraphrase as "He decided to make that confession his swan song."

Comment: "Swan song" has too much of an air of morbid finality in my opinion. It would only be used if the confessor was actually or figuratively dying

Comment: Not everything is to be taken literally brother, if you catch my drift. :-)

Comment: Err, maybe I don't catch your drift, but the issue is that phrase ("swan song") has a well understood subtext that implies finality. From my reading of the OP, the "finality" of the situation is not the most important part, it is the last-minuteness of it :)